# some errors happen Map is not function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

does string array have map function ? 
it doesn't seem that String array has map and loop functions or something.
I have no idea to solve this problem.

```
List:string[] = ["a","b","c"]

<CheckList {...props.List} />


const CheckList = (checks: string[]) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {checks.map(item => {
        return <p>{item}</p>;
      })}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code your are spreading list items as individual props. You have to pass the list as an array.

Try this.

```
List:string[] = ["a","b","c"]

<CheckList checks={props.List} />


const CheckList = ({ checks }: {checks: string[]}) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {checks.map(item => {
        return <p>{item}</p>;
      })}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: I am sorry but following error happes. it seems to be correct  thoug.....  Type '{ checks: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & string[]'.
  Property 'checks' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & string[]'.  TS2322

Answer (score 1):

Sohail's answer is correct, in that you're not passing it in properly, but it needs to be passed in as part of the props object.

Because it's a react component, it still needs to accept props, it can't take the string array as an arg.

```
interface CheckListProps {
  checks: string[];
}

const CheckList = ({ checks }: CheckListProps) => {
// ...
```